# pnpm install a library inside micro frontend

Tags: pnpm

I am using pnpm workspaces with turborepo, and I'm having issues installing packages.

I want to install a package only for a certain application/workspace, eg. portals/cashout

Whenever I do

```
pnpm install lodash
```

It would warn me that this would be global workspace, which is not what I need.

I need something like

```
pnpm install lodash --workspace=portals/cashout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [filtering](https://pnpm.io/filtering)

To filter by path:

```
pnpm add lodash --filter=./portals/cashout
```

To filter by package name, you can specify the name of the package. For instance:

```
pnpm add lodash --filter=cashout
```

You can also just change the directory to `portals/cashout` and run installation there.